# How do debug Sharepoint 404 errors

Tags: central-administration, page-not-found, 404

I made a configuration change to my SharePoint 2010 Web Application [(earlier question)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4358/cannot-enable-anonymous-access-for-publishing-site) that enabled Anonymous access and now my site returns 404 errors!?  Even when I change the setting back it does not resolve the error.  To make matters worse now my Central Admin site returns the same 404 error.  Looking at the source for the 404 error page I see an HttpError...CheckSuspiciousPhysicalPath.

Any ideas on how to debug this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 404's I generally check this

- Can anyone else access the page?
- Is the master page published?
- does the user have permissions to the user page?
- Is the page layout published?
- does the user have permissions to the page layout?
- any other resources, such as controls (ASCX) not available to the user with 404's

For anonymous sites I will most often solve it after verifying publishing status and permissions on the master page.

Answer (score 0):

My tools of choice for this would be [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/version.asp), to see what is going on at the HTTP level, and [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see what happens on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Havent tried it, but I saw this trick for SharePoint 404's: http://blog.mediawhole.com/2010/02/sharepoint-404-resource-cannot-be-found.html

Answer (score 0):

Yeah View Source when you see that error and the stack trace will usually point you directly to the control or reference that's missing.